# UILabel - Alternative for Deprecated Method "adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel

So in my code, I was checking if my characters fit in my Label or not and had the following line :

```
return self.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth;
```

This was placed in an implementation of `UILabel`. Can someone tell me just what is the exact alternative for this? The documentation says - Use `NSKernAttributeName`, but I wasn't quite able to understand that. Can someone help me on this?

In the larger sense - The method is called as:

```
xLab.adjustLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
```

In my code, I have:

```
@implementation UILabel ()
- (BOOL) getter {
    return self.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth;
}

- (void) setter:(BOOL) setVal {
     self.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = setVal;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your `getter` and `setter` are entirely superfluous as shown; wherever you call `getter` and/or `setter`, you could simply get/set `adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth` directly.

As for the question of how to do auto-kerning with `NSKernAttributeName`, Apple's documentation says: “To turn on auto-kerning in the label, set `NSKernAttributeName` of the string to `[NSNull null]`”, i.e., you would do something like:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *s;
s = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:my_uilabel.text];
[s addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
          value:[NSNull null]
          range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];
my_uilabel.attributedText = s;
```

But if you did not want to do automatic adjustment of letter spacing but rather find out whether the text fits in the label or not, you might want to check the various methods in [`NSString` UIKit additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html). (This guess of intent is based on the wording in the original question.)

Comment: Hmmm... so after checking the ui_label.text, should I check if the value obtained from the NSKernAttributeName is a non-zero, so as to return the Boolean as you can see in the Getter? Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: @gran_profaci You would need to get the property `attributedText` and check whether it has the attribute `NSKernAttributeName` set to `[NSNull null]` over the range of the entire string in order to know whether automatic kerning is enabled. Note that it's possible to only set the attribute for half of the string or for different parts of the string, etc.

Comment: Do I need to enumerate it? And then check if the value is non-zero?

Comment: @gran_profaci See the class `NSAttributedString` for methods on how to get the attributes of the string. And to detect auto-kerning you would need to check that the value is exactly `[NSNull null]`. The same attribute could exist with a different (and non-zero) value to set manual kerning. And the same attribute can exists multiple times in different locations on the same string. I am almost certain that you don't even want to do what you are planning to do, and in any case the attributed strings do not exactly map to the old behaviour you are trying to emulate.