# Using NSKernAttributeName in Place of "setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth"

Tags: ios, objective-c

Just started learning objective C for iOS apps, I am trying to remove the deprecated code from an app for use in xcode 11, noticed a warning for `setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth`, checked the apple documentation which suggested me to use `NSKernAttributeName`. The documentation didn't provide much help at all in terms of using it, based on research on the use of `NSKernAttributeName`, I tried utilizing it in my code such as shown below.

Initial code with `setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth`

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
   self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
   self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
   self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
   if ([self.titleLabel respondsToSelector:@selector
                        (setAdjustsLetterSpacngToFitWidth:)]) {
                        [self.titleLabel setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth:YES];
   }
```

Code utilizing `NSKernAttributeName` (used Arkku's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923763/uilabel-alternative-for-deprecated-method-adjustsletterspacingtofitwidth?answertab=active#tab-top) as reference to try using it)

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
   self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
   self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
   self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
   if ([self.titleLabel respondsToSelector:@selector
                        (NSKernAttributeName:)]) {
                        [self.titleLabel addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                                               value:[NSNull null];
                                               range:NSMakeRange(0, self.titleLabel)];
   }
```

I understand the concept of kerning, what I really don't understand though is how I should go about refactoring this to utilize `NSKernAttributeName`. `self.titleLabel` seems like it is quite similar to `UILabel`.Can anyone provide any suggestions on how I should go about tackling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[self.titleLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth:)]`

[`respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector?language=objc) tells you if the receiver (`self.titleLabel`) implements or inherits a method that can respond to a specified message (`setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth:`). In other words if you can call this method (send a message) on the `self.titleLabel`.

> `[self.titleLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(NSKernAttributeName:)])`

- [`NSKernAttributeName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nskernattributename) is one of the [`NSAttributedStringKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey?language=objc)s you can apply to text in an attributed string. It's NOT a method on `self.titleLabel` (`UILabel`).
- [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring?language=objc) is a string that has associated attributes (such as visual style, hyperlinks, or accessibility data) for portions of its text.
- [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel?language=objc) has the [`attributedText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620542-attributedtext?language=objc) property you can use to display attributed string.

Create attributed string from scratch:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    // As a first step you have to create attributes for attributed string
    // It's a dictionary of attribute name & value pairs
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
        NSKernAttributeName: @-0.9
    };

    // Create attributed string with custom attributes
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.titleLabel.text
                                                                     attributes:attributes];

    // Assign it to UILabel
    self.titleLabel.attributedText = attrString;
}
```

Add attributes to the existing one:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    // As a first step you have to create attributes for attributed string
    // It's a dictionary of attribute name & value pairs
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
        NSKernAttributeName: @-0.9
    };

    // Create mutable attributed string from existing attributed string
    // Be aware that the self.titleLabel.attributedText can be nil
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.titleLabel.attributedText];
    [attrString addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length)];

    // Assign it back to UILabel
    self.titleLabel.attributedText = attrString;
}
```

Possible values:

- `NSNumber` with float

  - `0` - kerning disabled
  - `!= 0` - kerning enabled
- `NSNull`

  - auto kerning<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Not sure if it still works as it's no longer in the documentation.

---

> `NSKernAttributeName: @-0.9` can I ask what this value does? Even when I set it to zero or some other value i noticed that there's no change.

- `@-0.9` is a shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:-0.9]`.
- Negative values moves characters closer.

[image]

> I wanted to ask specifically why did you create a dictionary of attributes?

It's required to provide them as `NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey, id> *`, which is a dictionary of attribute & value pairs. You're not forced to create a dictionary upfront, you can pass it directly, whatever you want:

```c
self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
self.titleLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hallo [NSNull null]"
                                                                 attributes:@{ NSKernAttributeName: [NSNull null] }];
```

Comment: `NSKernAttributeName: @-0.9` can I ask what this value does? even when I set it to zero or some other value i noticed that there's no change. Also it appears that in my code `self.titleLabel` is `null`, I'd have to go dive deeper into it. I wanted to ask specifically why did you create a dictionary of attributes? Apart from these questions, I appreciate the help! this is very informative.

Comment: One more thing Id like to ask though, what happens if the kerning isn't working though (like you're not seeing the changes in the spacing between the letters)? could it mean that the value isn't a string or number? but something else? It seems im getting the data from an API but im wondering how comes it has no effect really in changing the width.

Comment: As a first thing, replace the value from your API with a hardcoded one like `@-0.9`. Do you see the change? Yes? Then data from your API are wrong or aren't converted correctly. But we're getting off-topic with this comment - comments are not for additional/unrelated questions - the initial question was about kerning, label, attributed string and we shouldn't be talking about data from an API.

Comment: alright, ill go mark your post as the answer. It solved my problem of removing the deprecated code. My bad on getting off-topic. Just wanted to know the reason if it wasnt working which was a result of the data not being of a certain type. I hardcoded it though and I don't see any change in the spacing.